# How do I view logs in raw text in Azure Logs for Azure Spring Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-spring-cloud, azure-spring-boot

I have a query where I can look at the logs for the past half an hour for my spring app. (See screenshot).

The query returns everything in a tabular format. But I would like to view the raw text. How do I view the raw text?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- AFAIK, unfortunately it is not possible to view the query results in raw text.
- By default, these filtered logs will be in tabular format.
- You can export the queried logs to **CSV**, **Excel** and Power BI formats as shown below:
- Run the query=> Click on **Export**=> Select the format you want to export your logs to.

[image]

[image]

**References:**

[Quickstart - Monitoring Azure Spring Apps apps with logs, metrics, and tracing | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/quickstart-logs-metrics-tracing?tabs=Azure-CLI&pivots=programming-language-java#log-analytics-1)